# Spring Boot selenium integration test with Headless Chrome runs very slow

Tags: spring, selenium, spring-boot, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Spring Boot web application and some integration tests that run with selenium. All my integration tests inherit from:

### BootIntegracaoTest.java

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT, classes = EaudApplication.class)
@ActiveProfiles(value = "default,teste")
public abstract class BootIntegracaoTest {

    @Autowired public Environment env;

    static {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS ? "target/test-classes/chromedriver_win32.exe" : "target/test-classes/chromedriver_linux64");

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--headless");
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        SeleniumQuery.$.driver().use(driver);
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> $.driver().quit()));
    }
}
```

If i take off the --headless argument, the tests runs on normal time. With headless argument, it runs really.

I've enabled chromedriver log and it seem's to be slow when waiting for some request: `[17.289][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...`

I'm using Selenium 2.53.1 and ChromeDriver: 2.32

I also have tried lots of chromium flags, but no success. If anybody has any similar issue that could help, thanks.

Comment: The initial size of the window can have an impact on the content. Try to define one: `options.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");` I would also check the logs from the browser to see if there's an issue triggered by the headless mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer might be too late, but might help someone in future.

Try out these two ChromeOptions:

```
options.addArguments("--proxy-server='direct://'");
options.addArguments("--proxy-bypass-list=*");
```

Comment: You're a god. Thanks!